# Write a Mule 4 Custom Policy with a Scripting Module inside

Tags: mulesoft

In Mule 4 is it possible to create a Custom policy and use a Scripting Module inside? I'm developing a Custom policy using the maven archetype, here is a code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
  xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"     
  xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
  ...
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http-policy-transform/current/mule-http-policy-transform.xsd      
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting 
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">


  <http-policy:proxy name="{{{policyId}}}-custom-policy">
    <http-policy:source>    
        
        <logger level="INFO" message="Version 1.2.2" />     
        <logger level="INFO" message="Started custom policy execution"/>

        ...

        <set-variable variableName="aud" value="{{{audience}}}"/>
        <http-policy:execute-next/>     
        <logger level="INFO" message="Finished custom policy execution"/>
    </http-policy:source>
</http-policy:proxy>
```

The Custom policy works when I deploy it to CloudHub, however it doesn't work if I insert a Scripting Module inside:

```
<http-policy:proxy name="{{{policyId}}}-custom-policy">
    <http-policy:source>    
        
        <logger level="INFO" message="Version 1.2.2" />     
        <logger level="INFO" message="Started custom policy execution"/>

        ...

        <set-variable variableName="aud" value="{{{audience}}}"/>

        <scripting:execute engine="groovy" doc:name="Execute"> <!-- This part doesn't run at all! -->
            <scripting:code>                
                
                import java.net.MalformedURLException;
                import java.net.URL;
                import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

                log.info('Inside Groovy script execute')    
                flow = registry.lookupByName("myFlow").get();
                if(attributes.headers['Authorization']) 
                ...
```

I have the dependencies and required namespaces for Scripting Module and Groovy, the maven build and deployment ofthe custom policy work fine, but when I activate and test the policy it doesn't run the `<scripting:execute>` and doesn't skip it either, it just stops.

Answer (score 0):

From Custom Policy Development Reference:

If a policy needs to use custom code, the policy can either:

1. Import a custom Mule plugin programmed with the Java or XML SDK Extension
2. Use the scripting:execute element to add in custom scripts